# Efficiently changing field names added by Extract Multi Values to Points tool in ArcPy for large dataset?

Tags: arcpy, raster

How can I change the name of the composite raster of multiple bands as below- I think this may be the solution to efficiently address this problem but you are welcome for further solution?

[image: demo]

I have a composite raster, `Proximity_Rasters_NoHNSN.tif`, which is produced by vertically stacking several other rasters.I need to extract all the band-wise values into a point layer in arcmap.

Now I am using [Extract Multi Values to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-multi-values-to-points.htm) tool to extract band-wise values into a point layer which will be used for further analysis. But the problem is- the field added to the point layer after running this tool is not quite trackable since this tool adds fields like `b1_Proximity_Rasters_NoHNSN.tif` , `b2_Proximity_Rasters_NoHNSN.tif`...just prepending the `b and band number` to the raster name as you see.So I think running this tool after changing the band names will give me a meaningful and trackable result.

The field names added by Extract Multi Values to Points tool are as below:
[image: dem]

**How I am solving my problem now:**

Now I am using arcpy to solve this problem by creating a new field and copying corresponding value into it and deleting the field after copying, but this way is too much time-consuming since I am dealing with large data.

---

Added code since @PolyGeo was guiding:

```
#Change field names
ffields = sorted([i.name  for i in arcpy.ListFields(eq_smpled_pnts) if re.match(r"b\d_", i.name)])
for old_fld in ffields:
    indx = int(re.findall(r'^b(\d{1,})', old_fld)[0])-1
    new_fld = raster_bands_names[indx]
    arcpy.AddField_management(in_table=eq_smpled_pnts, field_name=new_fld, field_type="DOUBLE", field_precision="12", field_scale="", field_length="25", field_alias="", field_is_nullable="NULLABLE", field_is_required="NON_REQUIRED", field_domain="")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table=eq_smpled_pnts, field=new_fld, expression= "!%s!"%new_fld, expression_type="PYTHON", code_block="")
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(eq_smpled_pnts, new_fld)
```

---

**Update:**
After trying @GISGe suggestion I found that all work correctly but the band1 does not change the name as intended!!See the screenshot of the script run as below:

Script I used to rename each band:

```
#Change composite band name
def band_name_changer(image_stack_path,names_ordered_list):
    raster_describe_object = arcpy.Describe(image_stack_path)
    if len(raster_describe_object.children) != len(names_ordered_list):
        raise Exception("Input raster names length and number of bands in the stacked image is not equal.......")
    else:
        for bnd in enumerate(raster_describe_object.children):
            indx_bnd = bnd[0]
            input_path = bnd[1].catalogpath
            output_path = os.path.join(os.path.split(input_path)[0], names_ordered_list[indx_bnd])
            arcpy.Rename_management(in_data=input_path, out_data=output_path, data_type="RasterBand")
```

But the output is ok except the `BAND_1`??

[image: error]

Comment: I've tried the [Rename tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/rename.htm) and it works with a raster band. Will add it as answer if your question is reopenend

Comment: I think this question should be closed because you are asking for help with code without showing us a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried so far i.e. "I am using arcpy to solve this problem by creating a new field and copying corresponding value into it and deleting the field after copying".  However, I will leave it open for now because @GISGe says that they have an answer to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just not use the functionality of the "Extract multivalues to points" tool with it's built in ability to cast an output field names of your choosing?

ExtractMultiValuesToPoints("observers.shp", [["elevation", "ELEV"], 
                           ["costraster", "COST"], ["flowdir", "DIR"]], "NONE")

Comment: Yes it worked! Very simple solution I did not catch at all. damn.

Answer (score 1):

So, the [Rename](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/rename.htm) tool allows you to rename a raster band. It can overwrite the name in the input dataset so you're not obliged to create a different output:

[image]

This will solve the issue prior to running the Extract Multivalues to Point tool, but you can also modify the output of this tool: with [Alter field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/alter-field-properties.htm), you can overwrite field names, again without intermediate steps or temporary results (but is works only with GDB feature classes, not with shapefiles or SDE feature classes).

Comment: Of course, only rename is the preferable, since I am working with more than 20 fields and more than 6 crore features, here in comparison of the alter field method but this rename tweak is not doing the job as you see in the updated question.

Comment: Well this is strange, your script works fine for me, all bands are renamed according to the provided list.

Comment: Same here I tried with other rasters that work fine but this does not. And tired of retrying..